# Installing serf with scons as a prerequisite for SVN 1.8.9 -> no serf binary

Tags: macos, svn, installation

I am running SVN 1.8.9 on Mac OSX 10.8.5. Currently the command "svn log" fails in a given repo with the error message:

```
svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'https://...'
```

My research showed that this is due to SVN having been compiled from source without the flag "--with-serf".

So, I downloaded and built serf (with its dependencies APU and APR) using the scons build tool as per the instructions. All went fine, but after installation, there is no serf binary command available. When I type 'serf' in the shell, I get the command not found error. Searching for a serf binary on my machine also doesn't give any results.

What might have gone wrong during the intallation? 
Where should binary be and why isn't there?
Are there any workarounds to install SVN with serf? 
(I tried 'brew install --build-from-source svn', but this doesn't seem to include the serf dependency either)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did:

1. Download [latest SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/download/)
2. Download the [latest](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scons/files/latest/download?source=files) [SCONS](http://www.scons.org/).
3. cd ~/Downloads/
4. tar -zxvf "latest SCONS".tar.gz
5. tar -zxvf "latest SVN".tar.gz
6. cd "latest SCONS"
7. python setup.py install
8. cd ~/Downloads/"latest SVN"
9. sh get-deps.sh serf
10. cd serf
11. scons install
12. cd ..
13. ./configure --with-serf
14. make install

Comment: I want to give you a hug. You just helped dig me out of hours of frustration with a concise and easy to follow procedure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error here and solved by following this post:

- https://ahmadawais.com/installing-svn-subversion-on-yosemite-after-removing-the-old-version/

I had to remove some old references to subversion inside:

- /usr/local/include/subversion-1/
- /usr/local/include/serf-1/

Answer (score 0):

Building Subversion is a pain due to the dozens of dependency issues. Usually Apache httpd has to be rebuilt with Subversion too, and then there's the APR library.

The easiest solution is to download a package that has everything you need. CollabNet doesn't have a Macintosh server package, but [Wandisco](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download) does. (Look for Yosemite down the Macintosh list). This will include Apache, Subversion, and the Subversion client all in one package.

I haven't used Wandisco's package before. However, I can tell you that CollabNet installs everything under `/opt/collabnet` including a new and complete Apache server. This also sets up `/etc/init.d` to start this Apache server and disables the original. I assume a similar thing happens with Wandisco (although Mac OS X doesn't use `/etc/init.d`, but Launch Services).

This is probably way easier than attempting to configure your Mac with everything you need for Subversion.